# mutex or atomic in const member function

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

I am reading Item 16 in Scott Meyers's Effective Modern C++.
In the later part of the item, he says

> For a single variable or memory location requiring synchronization, use of a `std::atomic` is adequate, but once you get to two or more variables or memory locations that require manipulation as a unit, you should reach for 
>   a mutex.

But I still don't see why it is adequate in the case of a single variable or memory location, take the polynomial example in this item

```
class Polynomial {
 public:
 using RootsType = std::vector<double>;
 RootsType roots() const
 {
   if (!rootsAreValid) { // if cache not valid
    .... // **very expensive compuation**, computing roots,
         // store them in rootVals
   rootsAreValid = true;
  }
 return rootVals;
}
private:
mutable  std::atomic<bool> rootsAreValid{ false };
mutable RootsType rootVals{};
};
```

My question is:

If thread 1 is in the middle of heavily computing the `rootVals` before the `rootAreValid` gets assigned to `true`, and thread 2 also calls function `roots()`, and evaluates `rootAreValid` to `false`, then thread 2 will also steps into the heavy computation of `rootVals`, so for this case how an atomic `bool` is adequate? I still think a `std::lock_guard<mutex>` is needed to protect the entry to the `rootVals` computation.

Comment: It isn't adequate, obviously. The quote says *"For a single variable or memory location requiring synchronization..."*

Comment: @juanchopanza, well, isn't this an example the case of "For a single variable or memory location requiring synchronization"?

Comment: No, you need to synchronize the vector too.

Comment: Really in this case you need another flag to check if there is a thread that is running the expensive computation.  Was this example from the book or is this your own scenario?

Comment: @Allanqunzi No, this is a vector containing an unknown number of member variables.

Comment: @NathanOliver, it's from the book. But I didn't realize there are variables `rootVals` and `rootAreValid` are being synchronized.

Comment: @Allanqunzi If you found that code in the book, it's most likely meant to illustrate that `atomic` is inadequate for this.

Comment: Strangely enough, when I look at my copy of the book, I find no place where he uses std::atomic in his Polynomial code.

Comment: @MikelF, I added `std::atomic` for better illustration of my question.

Comment: @Allanqunzi That makes sense. However, you are representing the code as directly from the book rather than modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example there are two variables being synchronized : `rootVals` and `rootsAreValid`. That particular item is referring to the case where *only* the atomic value requires synchronization. For example :

```
#include <atomic>

class foo
{
public:
    void work()
    {
        ++times_called;
        /* multiple threads call this to do work */
    }
private:
    // Counts the number of times work() was called
    std::atomic<int> times_called{0};
};
```

`times_called` is the only variable in this case.

Comment: I see, thanks, I did't realize that there are two variables are being synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to avoid unnecessary heavy computation using the following code:

```
class Polynomial {
 public:
 using RootsType = std::vector<double>;

 RootsType roots() const
 {
   if (!rootsAreValid) { // Acquiring mutex usually is not cheap, so we check the state without locking
     std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_guard(sync);
     if (!rootsAreValid) // The state could changed because the mutex was not owned at the first check
     {
       .... // **very expensive compuation**, computing roots,
           // store them in rootVals
     }
     rootsAreValid = true;
  }
  return rootVals;
}
private:
mutable std::mutex sync;
mutable std::atomic<bool> rootsAreValid{ false };
mutable RootsType rootVals{};
};
```

Comment: Checking `rootsAreValid` (a regular bool) is unprotected (outside of the mutex) This is a classical example of a data race and therefore invalid. The problem is extended to the vector which is returned while unsynchronized with the thread that wrote to it... This results in undefined behavior

Comment: @LWimsey, there is no data race. The value `rootsAreValid` cannot change from `true` to `false`. Data race may occur when two of more threads try to calculate the vector when `rootsAreValid` is false but this part of code is guarded by mutex and additional comparison is made. The reason why the first check is unguared is performance because atomic operations consume dozens of ticks.

Comment: You misunderstand what a data race is: _multiple threads that access the same memory location simultaneously and (at least) one of them is a writer_.. 
That applies to `rootsAreValid` and the fact that it cannot change from `true` to `false` is irrelevant. Yes, the `mutex` guarantees that only a single thread can write to the `vector`, but that does not guarantee that the `vector` is correctly synchronized to a reader thread since reader access is outside of the `mutex`............(_continues_)

Comment: (_continued_)............  Your code shows an (invalid) implementation of the _Double-Checked Locking Pattern_.  If you check your source you will find that `rootsAreValid` is not a `bool`, but a `std::atomic<bool>` (or equivalent).
And that will exactly fix the problem (`std::atomic` is a data-race-free type) and it will cause the `vector` to be synchronized based on the implicit acquire/release semantics of (default) atomic loads & stores.

Comment: @LWimsey, `vector` does not need synchronized access when because it is not changed after initialization. The validity of this pattern is compiler specific due to compiler optimizations. Modern compilers should not have problems.

Comment: Changing `rootsAreValid` from `bool` to `std::atomic<bool>` will decrease the performance.

Comment: If you are worried about performance, an atomic load/acquire on X86 is as cheap as a regular load. Only on weaker platforms such as Power or ARMv7 there is a small price to pay. But I am more concerned about correctness

Comment: @LWimsey, Yes, there is no atomic load/store on x86 for `bool` type because memory read is already atomic. So `std::atomic<bool>` will act the same as `bool` except the case when it is wrongly optimized by a compiler. I agree that `std::atomic<bool>` is better in this case

Comment: There is more to `std::atomic` than just the atomicity of stores and loads. It provides memory ordering guarantees and that is why a correct DCLP implementation needs this type; It is correct now